# How to start AWS EMR JAR execution (Step) upon S3 data update or change on persistent (Waiting) cluster? Best practice or general approach

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr

Looking for best practice or general approach.  AWS EMR cluster is persistent and JAR Step runs to completion (Mahout Recommender example).  When input file in S3 gets updated data need to immediately execute JAR (Step). Rinse, repeat.  Should solution with cluster settings, bootstrap script, JAR code, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create workflow and schedule it.

Workflow should have these:

1. Check new data arrived to a designated location
2. If there is new directory then kick off the step to process updated data set
3. Also once processed archive the data

Once you have scripts for workflow, you can schedule in bastion/client server either using cron or advanced tools like azkaban.